# Element not in a list with Python 3

Tags: python

I'm using Python 3, what I want is to identify whether a word is in a text file or not.

Content of the text file:

```
test
test
test
```

My code:

```
    wordsUsedFilename = "usedwords.txt"
f = open(wordsUsedFilename, 'r')
usedWords = [line.strip() for line in f]
words = []
words.append("test")
check = True
while check:
    for word in words:
        if word not in usedWords:
            print("Not in the list") 
        else:
            print("In the list")
            check = False
```

The problem is that the program should stop but it keeps running considering that the word is not in the list, what did I did wrong ?

Comment: I see an infinite loop but no `break` in code

Comment: `if word not in words:` will never be `True` because word just came out of `words`

Comment: @thefourtheye corrected but still doesn't work The "break" ? Should I really put a "break" ? If it's false it will stop running isn't it ?

Comment: First iteration, lets say it exhausts the `for` loop, it will check if `while`'s condition is `False`. That can never be Truthy. So, the `while` loop will be executed infinite times.

Comment: @thefourtheye Thank you I cleaned the code, but still got the same error, it is more explicit now as you can see, it'll keeps writing "Not in the list", I'm sure that the test word is in my list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
f = open(wordsUsedFilename, 'a+')
```

The `'a+'` mode appends to the end of the file... which is where it starts reading from the file as well. Change it to `'r'` and you're golden.

P.S. You're better off using `set` to store the word list:

```
usedWords = set()
with open(wordsUsedFilename, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        usedWords.add(line.strip())
```

Here's the whole thing:

```
wordsUsedFilename = "usedwords.txt"
usedWords = set()
with open(wordsUsedFilename, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        usedWords.add(line.strip())
words = []
words.append("test")
for word in words:
    if word not in usedWords:
        print("Not in the list") 
    else:
        print("In the list")
```

And it works for me:

```
$ more usedwords.txt 
test
test
test
$ python practice.py 
In the list
```

Answer (score 0):

For what you seem to be doing you can just check against the whole block of data.

```
wordsUsedFilename = "usedwords.txt"
words = ["test"]
f = open(wordsUsedFilename, 'r')
text= f.read()
for word in words:
    if word in text:
        print("{} in {}".format(word, wordsUsedFilename))
```

Comment: Thanks for the alternative